# Variable defined but still unable to be resolved

Tags: java

I'm learning java and was reading about methods in a text book. There is a program example to create a Celsius to Fahrenheit conversion table. I thought it would be a good idea to type into Eclipse and run the program. The program is below. Even thought it is exactly as the text in the book, I get the following error

> c cannot be resolved to a variable

In the `int f = (int) celsiusToFahrenheit`, and in `println(c + "C = "` lines. It appears that `c` is defined in the for loop as int so not sure what is wrong. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
/*
 * File: TermperatureConversionTable.java
 * ---------------------
 * This program creates a table of Celsius to Fahrenheit
 * equivalents using a function to perform the conversion.
 */

import acm.program.*;

public class TemperatureConversionTable extends ConsoleProgram {

    public void run() {
        println("Celsius to Fahrenheit table.");
        for (int c = LOWER_LIMIT; c <= UPPER_LIMIT; c += STEP_SIZE); {
            int f = (int) celsiusToFahrenheit(c);
            println(c + "C = " + f + "F");
        }
    }
/* Returns the Fahrenheit equivalent of the Celsius temperature c. */
    private double celsiusToFahrenheit(double c) {
        return 9.0 / 5.0 * c + 32;
    }

/* Private constants*/
    private static final int LOWER_LIMIT = 0;
    private static final int UPPER_LIMIT = 100;
    private static final int STEP_SIZE = 5;
}
```

Comment: Semicolon before open-brace in the for loop.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera if it is not Java, what is it?

Comment: I am pretty sure this is in fact Java..... And why so many votes to close?

Comment: @KickButtowski `println()` should have a import else this is not going to be compile at least.. so not `Java`

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera good point so better say the code has some syntax issues.

Answer (score 3):

Small syntactical error with a semicolon after the for-expression in your loop. Everything else looks fine to me.

```
    for (int c = LOWER_LIMIT; c <= UPPER_LIMIT; c += STEP_SIZE); //<---remove the semicolon 
    {
        int f = (int) celsiusToFahrenheit(c);
        println(c + "C = " + f + "F");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is with the for loop, which is never actually looped due to an extra  semicolon.

```
for (int c = LOWER_LIMIT; c <= UPPER_LIMIT; c += STEP_SIZE); {
                                             remove this   ^
```

Because of the semicolon, you terminate the statement, the following braces will just change the scope of that block of code, which wherein `c` is infact not defined.

Comment: if you can explain why such behavior happens when you have ; at that location I gladly vote u up

Comment: Thanks quix, but I think he was looking for an expansion on my code-only response - I already added in my little blurb about why it is so.

Comment: @quixotrykd thank you for your input. but I try encourage other to have better answer so other can learn out of it not just copy and past an answer.

Comment: Don't apologize! Your comments are appreciated! I shouldn't have prematurely posted :D

Answer (score 1):

A small mistake at `for` statement.

```
for (int c = LOWER_LIMIT; c <= UPPER_LIMIT; c += STEP_SIZE); {
            int f = (int) celsiusToFahrenheit(c);
            println(c + "C = " + f + "F");
        }
```

Putting `;` before `{` will terminate the loop without body and that's the cause of getting error as variable `c` is not defined in the body.

Refer: [The for statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)